# Define Spotfire Axis Range for Text Values

Tags: spotfire

I have a Scatter Plot which is incorrectly ordering its textual values. I can't post a picture, but I will describe it. The X-Axis is currently ordered left to right as 'None to Very Low' -> 'Medium' -> 'Low' -> and 'High'. I'd like for it to be ordered 'None to Very Low' -> 'Low' -> 'Medium' -> 'High'. There is not any obvious way to change the ordering. How can I correct this?

Comment: Can you provide us the code you use. The description is too vague and open to interpretation otherwise.

Comment: I'm just using the built-in chart function. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/HlKguC4.jpg) is a screenshot of how it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can adjust the order of values in a column:

1. from the **Edit** menu, select **Column Properties**
2. make sure the correct data table is selected from the dropdown at the top of this dialog
3. locate and select the [Effort] column
4. click the **Sort Order** tab
5. choose **Custom sort order** and then click the **Configure...** button
6. adjust the order as desired

more details with screenshots in the Spotfire documentation: http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/data/data_details_on_column_properties_sort_order.htm

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much for your help. I'm surprised I hadn't found this solution through much Googling.